# Shell or Perl script to rename folders from a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl

I'm trying t look for a way to rename folders in Linux via a shell or perl script based on the first two columns in a .txt file:

Example of text file
rename.txt

```
current_dir1     new_dir1
current_dir2     new_dir2
current_dir3     new_dir3
...
current_dir50    new_dir50
```

Then the shell/Perl script would create another file with all the mv commands to run based on what's in the list:

rename_folders.sh or .pl

```
#!/bin/ksh

mv /home/pete1/current_dir1 /home/pete1/new_dir1

mv /home/pete1/current_dir2 /home/pete1/new_dir2

mv /home/pete1/current_dir3 /home/pete1/new_dir3
........
mv /home/pete1/current_dir2 /home/pete1/new_dir2
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: And can you show what you've done toward it?  Then you'd have a legitimate question.

Comment: This have be a script and not a tool like `rename`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
folder_path="/home/pete1/"
while read -r oldname newname; do 

     # remove echo if happy with result
     # if you remove echo it will rename
     echo mv "$folder_path/$oldname" "$folder_path/$newname"; 

done < rename.txt
```

If you make `done < rename.txt`  to `done < rename.txt >somefile.sh` it will write all commands which is result of `echo`